# Travis displaying build error when build was passed

Tags: mocha.js, travis-ci

travis badge fails to show build status is passing

i have tried copying the readme badge to show my build status but still keeps on showing build error on my repository

```
my test scripts
  "scripts": { 
    "start": "node ./build/app.js",
    "test": "npm run db:unmigrate && npm run db:migrate && npm run db:seedAll && npm run testing",
    "dev": "nodemon --exec babel-node app/app.js",
    "db:migrate": "babel-node app/server/migrations/migrate.js",
    "db:unmigrate": "babel-node app/server/migrations/unmigrate.js",
    "db:seedAll": "babel-node app/server/seed/seedAll.js",
    "testing": "nyc mocha --timeout 50000  -r esm --exit",
    "clean": "rm -rf build && mkdir build",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run build-babel",
    "build-babel": "babel -d ./build ./app -s",
    "generate-lcov": "nyc report --reporter=text-lcov > lcov.info",
    "codeclimate-coverage": "codeclimate-test-reporter < lcov.info",
    "coveralls-coverage": "coveralls < lcov.info",
    "coverage": "npm run test && npm run generate-lcov && npm run coveralls-coverage && npm run codeclimate-coverage"
  },

my test are run on a npm run test command my travis.yml file is below am using elephant sql

language: node_js
node_js:
 - "stable"
install: npm install
cache:
  directories:
    - "node_modules"
env: 
  - CODECLIMATE_REPO_TOKEN=be3fcca4d68c6d7f19c1ca6ba76517d6c01e6891b3
  - NODE_ENV=TEST
  - SECRET_KEY=nagasaki
after_success:
  - npm run coverage
```

Comment: What's the badge code? It may also just be a caching issue and requires a hard refresh

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by copying my travis badge into my readme.md from the travis build and pushing readme changes to my remote repository on github